# What is the meaning of base 10 in ValueError in Python3?

Tags: python

I was trying some outputs with int() and tried to convert a string containing char into an int.
And the following error was displayed.

```
a = '3ca'
b = int(a)
b
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c38dfdad7d80> in <module>
      1 a = '3ca'
----> 2 b = int(a)
      3 b

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3ca'
```

Can someone tell me what is the meaning of 'base 10' in the error?

Comment: Type `help(int)` in your interpreter and look at the definition of the constructor

Comment: `3ca` is not a valid integer. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @wjandrea - I was just trying to see how it describes the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` will always return a base-10 integer, but it needs to be given the base of the string it receives (if it is not base-10). `3ca` is not a base-10 string hence the error.

In this case, the base is ***probably*** 16, assuming `3ca` (`3CA`) represents a hexadecimal number.

```
print(int('3ca', base=16))
```

outputs

```
970
```

Comment: .plus one but *probably* they are just confused about the `int()` function and don't actually want this

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks. It was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It means you can't convert a string that includes letters to an integer in base 10 as letters are not part of the numbering system in base 10. Base 10 is our normal numbering system that humans use with symbols 0-9(as opposed to base 16 which includes the letter a-f).